# Spring throws the error: Bean definition is abstract

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I need some help with next topic.

I have a hierarchy of beans, just like that:

```
<bean id="father" class="myPackage.Father" abstract="true"/>  

<bean id="childA" class="myPackage.ChildA" parent="father">    
        <property name="atrib1" value="hello"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="childB" class="myPackage.ChildB" parent="father">  
        <property name="atrib2" value="bye"></property>  
        <property name="atrib3" value="other"></property>  
</bean>
```

I need to create another bean which contains a reference to the abstract class. Then at run-time, I will need to be able to initialize a variable of TYPE "myPackage.Father" and instantiate it with any of the children classes (the polymorphism mechanism). I mean something like that:

```
<bean id="reference" class="myPackage.Another"> 
        <property name="atrib4" ref="father"></property>
</bean>
```

Note that reference (an instance of myPackage.Another) is not a subclass of myPackage.Father. But with these lines Spring throws the next error:

```
Bean definition is abstract
```

How could I deal with it?

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: `abstract` on a bean definition has **NO** relationship to an abstract class. If you need another means of instantiating either define a `FactoryBean` which contains this logic or use a properties file which contains the referenced bean and use a `PropertyPlaceHolder` to replace it at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all abstract bean has nothing to do with the abstract class 
they don't even need to be mapped to a class.They are used to group the common properties shared by another beans.But you can not use an abstract bean as a ref to wire a property in another bean.
If your bean myPackage.Another has a reference of type myPackage.Father and your child beans are assignable (either extends of implements) to myPackage.Father then you can wire either childA or childB 
in your myPackage.Another bean like this

```
 <bean id="reference" class="myPackage.Another"> 
            <property name="atrib4" ref="childA"></property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: so you're telling me that at runtime if the instance 'reference' can take either of two values ​​children, then I will need the following bean definitions:                                                   

<bean id="referenceA" class="myPackage.Another">                      
        <property name="atrib4" ref="childA"></property>              
</bean>
<bean id="referenceB" class="myPackage.Another"> 
        <property name="atrib4" ref="childB"></property>
</bean>

Isn't it?

Comment: yes if you want two different bean of type myPackage.Another each with it's atrib4 wired with different child beans childA and childB

Answer (score 3):

abstract beans are never instantiated as objects, they exist only in the form of definitions.

From the documention:http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html
The parent bean cannot be instantiated on its own because it is incomplete, and it is also explicitly marked as abstract. When a definition is abstract like this, it is usable only as a pure template bean definition that serves as a parent definition for child definitions. Trying to use such an abstract parent bean on its own, by referring to it as a ref property of another bean or doing an explicit getBean() call with the parent bean id, returns an error. Similarly, the container's internal preInstantiateSingletons() method ignores bean definitions that are defined as abstract.

In your case

```
<bean id="reference" class="myPackage.Another"> 
        <property name="atrib4" ref="father"></property>
</bean>
```

is refering to the bean defined as abstract which is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know it is an abstract class, but my new question is how you can translate the following code java to beans:      myPackage.Father atrib4 = new myPackage.ChildA(). This is possible in java, but how to write with bean?

Comment: @CarlosSaric: in spring abstract="true" is used for template, so you can't directly refer to it, work around will be assign the property value during init phase,2- use the ref to childa object directly,  3- or a bean with another id which have parent Father and all implemented override behavior and then refer to that object..in simple, spring applicationcontext will resolve bean definition to object which is a concrete class. logically think how you are giving value for map in Spring, if you want to specify hastable separately you are giving definition for the same and referring to that

Answer (score 0):

There is no different between abstract class and abstract beans.When you use beans and refer to another bean which is abstract , it means you want to instantiate an abstract class it and it can not work surely !
Be careful when you are using an abstract class ! An abstract class is used for template class and you can just extend it !