# Cannot find service bean in controller

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I have a service that I am trying to autowire in my controller. Every time I build the application I get this error. I know I'm doing something wrong in my application context. Can anyone shed some light?

This is my project on git: https://github.com/zackh321/spring-swag

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

  <bean id="triangleService" class="com.zmags.interview.service.triangle.TriangleService" abstract="true">
    <property name="triangleController" ref="triangleController"></property>
  </bean>


</beans>
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'demoController' defined in file [/Users/zhyder/Desktop/springboot-swagger-test/spring-swag/target/classes/com/zmags/interview/controller/DemoController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zmags.interview.controller.DemoController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanIsAbstractException: Error creating bean with name 'triangleService': Bean definition is abstract
```

EDIT appContext

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

  <bean id="demoController" class="com.zmags.interview.controller.DemoController">
    <property name="triangleService" ref="triangleService"></property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: What do you think `Error creating bean with name 'triangleService': Bean definition is abstract` means?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It's saying that my Service interface is abstract right?

Comment: I see that you are trying to autowire ` @Autowired TriangleService triangleService; ` , Try to auto wire the implementation instead  `TriangleServiceImpl`

Comment: It's saying _Bean definition is abstract_.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094782/spring-throws-the-error-bean-definition-is-abstract

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397532/what-is-meant-by-abstract-true-in-spring

Comment: Your github code is using spring boot, then why are you using xml configuration? If you are using XML then your triangle service bean definition should be <bean id="triangleService" class="com.zmags.interview.service.triangle.TriangleServiceImpl"/> interface is not required to be declared in the bean configuration

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I updated the appContext above. Still not quite understanding what you are saying. When I run the app, it still complains about it needing a bean for triangleService

Comment: Everything should already be explained in those two links I shared (I will vote to close as duplicate once the day rolls over). If you still don't understand, ask yourself: what does _`abstract="true"`_ mean and do?

Comment: The Impl needs to be autowired, not the service, correct?

Comment: [_First of all abstract bean has nothing to do with the abstract class they don't even need to be mapped to a class.They are used to group the common properties shared by another beans.But you can not use an abstract bean as a ref to wire a property in another bean._](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19098046/438154)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm sorry, I don't understand that example when I compare the context to mine. Something is going over my head.

Comment: Ok, forget ALL of that. Why did you add `abstract="true"` to your bean definition in the XML?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153814/discussion-between-zack-and-sotirios-delimanolis).